# your local (non-existant) changes would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: git

I do `git checkout master` and I get the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    path/to/file.ext
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I do `git diff path/to/file.ext` and I don't see any differences at all. I do `git checkout -- path/to/file.ext` and then try `git checkout master` and I get the same error as above.

I can blow away my git repo and re clone it but if I do so I'll loose my other *actual* local changes.

I mean, maybe I've made changes to `path/to/file.ext`, as well, idk, but `git diff` leads me to conclude that I haven't

Any ideas?

Comment: This will be an end-of-line and/or file-name-case issue; but if you're sure you don't need to save the work-tree version of the file, you can simply delete it entirely and let `git checkout` fill in a new one from the other commit.

Answer (score 0):

I bet there are EOL-related changes hanging around your repo... specifically, on that file. Can you check the EOL file both in your working tree and on HEAD? You can do it on git bash like this:

```
git show HEAD:path-to-file.txt | file -
file path-to-file.txt
```

I bet they will end up having different EOL formats.

Comment: I get `/dev/stdin: PHP script text, ASCII text` for the first one and `path/to/file.ext: PHP script text, ASCII text` for the second one. idk what to make from that lol. Altho that said, I'd think that `git checkout -- path/to/file.ext` would render EOL differences moot?

Comment: It depends on your EOL settings..... if you have the (old) EOL handlers (like autocrlf) set up, you have gotten yourself into git's own version of EOL hell (probably unknowingly).